# Database mail not working / Nothing in queue or log

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

After configuring database mail on one server and sending a test email, I am finding nothing in the queue or the log.  The mail id, however, keeps incrementing with each retry.  I have checked the following:

- I am sysadmin on the box, so I do have permissions to send mail
- `EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_status_sp;` reports `STARTED`
- There are no records in the queue: `SELECT sent_account_id, sent_date FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_sentitems;`
- There are no records in the event log: `SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_event_log;`
- Service broker is enabled.  This returns "1": `SELECT is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'msdb';`

I have configured this successfully on 4 other instances, it's just one that is giving me grief. Any other pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Anything in `msdb.dbo.sysmail_allitems`? What's the fail of `sent_status` if so?

Comment: Ah, great!  There are records in there - all failed, except for the last which is `unsent`.  The last one I decided to delete existing profiles and start over, so perhaps that's why it is a different status.  How do I get it to go from here?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/configure-database-mail might help

Comment: @Tanner thanks, I spent some time there and on the troubleshooting pages already

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this issue is with a bug in the version of sql that I am running on this instance as explained here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3186435/fix-sql-server-2016-database-mail-does-not-work-on-a-computer-that-doe

Installing CU2 will fix it:

> **Note** This issue also affects instances that are running SQL Server
>   2016 SP1 CU1. This issue occurs because of a bug in SQL Server 2016
>   SP1 CU1 setup. The setup for SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU1 deletes the
>   config file DatabaseMail.exe.config without replacing it with a new
>   one. This causes the Database Mail to break in the absence of .Net
>   framework 3.5 SP1. The fix in SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU2 is meant to
>   address this issue and prevent the DatabaseMail.exe.config file from
>   getting deleted from the machine after installing a CU. So if you
>   install SQL Server 2016 SP1 + CU2, the Database Mail will not be
>   impacted by the setup. However, if the Database Mail is broken by the
>   installation of SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU1, you can use any one of the
>   workarounds mentioned below.